# Elephant.io integration php

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter

Using only a simple file I can get elephant.io to work, but If I'm trying to integrate it inside an class, it won't work.

The reason why it won't work is that it says I can't use `use elephant ...` inside a class or function.

How would I integrate elephant.io in an already existing class ?

To be more specific , I'm trying to integrate elephant.io into codeigniter framework.

```
    function tester() {

    use ElephantIO\Client,
        ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version1X;

        require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

        $client = new Client(new Version1X('http://www.textbasedmafiagame.com:8080'));


        $client->initialize();
        $client->emit('broadcast2', ['foo' => 'utførte et biltyveri']);
        $client->close();




    }
```

and get no response or outcome, but i do get:

```
use not allowed inside a function
```

and

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, the `use` keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. 
Try something along these lines

```
<?php    
use ElephantIO\Client, ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version1X;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

class foo{
  public function tester() {
     $client = new Client(new Version1X('http://www.textbasedmafiagame.com:8080'));
     $client->initialize();
     $client->emit('broadcast2', ['foo' => 'utførte et biltyveri']);
    $ client->close();
  }

}
```